# Azure json deployment add spoke route in existing hub route table

Tags: json, azure, templates, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I started recently to experiment with json and creating templates in Azure.
I've created an Azure json template to deploy a Vnet with Lock, NSG, Route Table, Spoke and Hub Peering. This is working, but the last bit is to create a route in an existing Hub Route Table.
This Hub Route Table holds all other routes from all Spoke Vnet Azure subscriptions.
Normally it's done with Powershell:

```
az network route-table route create -g $HubRgName --route-table-name $GatewayRT -n $VnetName --next-hop-type VirtualAppliance --address-prefix $NewSubnet --next-hop-ip-address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx --subscription $HubSubscriptionID
```

Comment: not sure if I understand. shouldn't routes be part of route table

Comment: Yes, the new route should be added to an existing Route Table. I have been trying to do this but when I run the template it overwrites the existing Route Table. Luckly for me I do have a Test environment. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hub, all Spokes, route table and routes should be in same deployment.

Don't be afraid to add new spoke and new routes to it and redeploy the whole thing again. This is so called desired state configuration, as it will figure out and only deploy the delta